# Should a review ban only apply to the queue the audit was failed in?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, review-suspension

Should users that that have less "sharpened" skills in one review queue be banned from *all* queues?

I can probably say with confidence that not everyone has evenly equal reviewing skills, therefore a user that's good at reviewing one queue is now banned from reviewing said queue because (s)he failed an audit in a different (sometimes unrelated) queue.

For example, User A is good at reviewing the Low Quality posts queue, but isn't as good at reviewing Suggested Edits, so if User A fails an audit in the SE queue (which is more likely) he's now banned from reviewing the LQ posts queue as well, which (IMO) seems like a waste of reviewing skills.

So I propose that instead of stopping users from using their "better" reviewing skills when they fail an audit, they only get banned from the queue that the audit was actually failed in.

Comment: If a user doesn't pay attention and/or overestimates his ability to do reviews in one queue, why do you assume this is different for other queues?

Comment: @l4mpi Because as I previously stated "*not everyone has evenly equal reviewing skills*", so it doesn't make sense if a user that fails a SE audit should be banned form, say the LQ queue, since IMO, reviewing SE's have little to do with the judgement of LQ posts.

Comment: Restating your baseless assumption does not make it any more of a valid argument. Do you have any facts backing it? Also, do you have any facts indicating this is even a problem in the first place?

Comment: @l4mpi I don't have any statistical evidence to prove that, it does however follow the basic human principle that everyone is different, different likes, methodologies, theologies, etc. Again, no, it just seemed logical to only ban users at what their worse at reviewing.

Comment: That applies the same to people who are good or bad at reviewing in general. As I said, either they pay attention or they don't; either they use the skip button if they are unsure how to review something or they don't. I don't see how this behaviour is vastly different for different queues.

Comment: Sam, if a user's making enough mistakes to even warrant a review ban, he/she's doing something __very__ wrong. (Like not paying any attention) Why would they be any good in other queues?

Comment: I just (wrongly) assumed there were users that genuinely wanted to learn how to review more accurately (and end up getting banned) but also happen to be decent reviewers in other queues.

Comment: The vast majority of the time folks get banned, it's because they were simply not paying close attention. That's not a problem specific to any one queue (although it tends to be particularly embarrassing for suggested edits).

Comment: The "assumption" made by the OP is common sense. If someone fails a course in Calculus, does that mean that they could never learn to speak German or play the piano? Should we just up and ban them from ever enrolling in school again until they "shape up" and learn Calculus?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my opinion: No.

A user should be able to recognize when he / she's having a more difficult time reviewing certain queues / questions / answers. If one's not completely sure on how to review a specific case, the user has the option, or even obligation, to "skip" it.

As far as I'm aware, these bans are often the result of users not paying attention in the review queue, (dis)agreeing with as many flags/suggested edits as possible just to get the badge. Users like that don't benefit the review system, and are more efficiently "dealt with", when the ban applies to all queues.

Frankly, reviewing is not something that requires a doctorate. If you're not sure on what to do with a case, skip it.

Comment: Seriously. If you're going to do it for the imaginary internet points, we at least expect you to raise your attention level to beat an audit. *often enough* to not get banned. The bar is so low, it only gets knocked over by people just shuffling their feet instead of trying to step over it.

Comment: @corsiKa: I couldn't have said it better, myself.

Comment: @corsiKa so how much is "often enough to not get banned"? I just had suspended for selection "Requires Editing", but on the same day I was reviewing I received the automated "thanks!" on other review tasks because my vote closed the consensus

Comment: @RichieV Well, the exact details are not published, but it's possible you just missed a few audits on that one queue while still doing fine on the other queue. I wouldn't worry too much about it - just accept it's not a perfect system that sometimes gets it wrong and enjoy the small break :-D