# This was in no way documentation: weird error message

Tags: discussion

I got this message when I went to review today:

```
This was in no way documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3060520/user3060520
Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.
```

I haven't reviewed in a couple of days, and I try very hard to determine what should be accepted and what shouldn't. The message isn't even clear and it blocks me from all forms of review. I also was never told there was a problem and I can't see the review I did badly on.

What is going on here?

Comment: My guess is the mod accidentally copied the wrong link into the ban message, probably because they had multiple tabs open, that user's profile as well as a post/edit/etc. that they're related to.

Comment: That linked profile page _did_ Approve something on Documentation that wasn't documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/103194?filter-tags=c . And you Approved it too. All of this supports @Servy's hypothesis.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, any idea why I'm blocked from all reviews?

Comment: @oldtechaa A review suspension is for all review queues. It's been discussed occassionally on Meta, for example [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261113/should-a-review-ban-only-apply-to-the-queue-the-audit-was-failed-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336498/this-was-in-no-way-documentation-weird-error-message#comment405523_336498) and [S.L. Barth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/812149/s-l-barth) have shown I probably did indeed get a review ban for [documentation that was actually a question](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/103194?filter-tags=c).

It is true I did not look closely at this edit, probably since the top of it looked like real doc code. The error message was probably a mistake by a moderator who looked at the edit, my profile, and the other reviewer's profile, and copied the wrong link into the ban message.

Comment: `Unable to have good values (-16777216 instead to 0) in C (beginner)` That is so obviously a question.

Comment: I can confirm that I have problems with copy-paste. Oops...